# How does mysql LIKE sort its results?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like

The way I understand it, when MySQL performs a `LIKE` query, depending on how you've set up your query `(%)string(%)`, the search string looks for exact text matches within your selected content.

I'm curious as to how and if the resulting rows are ordered according to matches found?

For example, if my query `LIKE` string `'frankly'` is queried against a table that has the following content:

```
id  content
-------------
1   frankly, i find cake rather delicious
2   frankly, i find cake repulsive, frankly
3   i currently live on franklyn street
```

Would any particular row be favored over the other?

Comment: An "EXPLAIN PLAN" will tell you whether your "LIKE" query is causing a sequential scan.  If it is, it will be returned in the order they are in the database, most likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySql doesn't guarantee an order for LIKE queries like that. In general, if you want a specific order, you will have to specify it using ORDER BY.

The specific order depends on many other factors, like join-type(Hash-join, Merge-join, etc) and data access method (index-scan, sequential scan, etc).

Comment: +1 Never rely on order if you haven't explicitly specify ordering.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is a kind of a filter.

Like doesn't really related with sort itself.

If you haven't add any explicit sort, rows are sorted by default(I guess by key).

Comment: In INNODB - by key, in MyISAM or more - by the row order in DB or other key used for other fields.

Comment: @Moshe, I don't think you can state so categorically that INNODB will always be by key.  Doesn't it depend a lot on what other parts of the query are there?

Comment: If the query does not have an ORDER clause, and have a other WHERE (for example, by  `cat=1` and with index `(cat,date)` the order will became by date in current version (and can change in MariaDB optimizations or other changes). It will work but do not trust it.